# Android with hibernate validator 7.x

Tags: java, android, hibernate-validator

I have already added hibernate validator with version `5.4.3.Final` and I have added the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.3.Final'
implementation 'javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4'
implementation 'org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4'
```

now, I changed dependencies with jakarta implementation and validator with version `7.0.5.Final`:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.5.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-cdi:7.0.5.Final'
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.el:4.0.1'
```

In runtime, right after using functionality related with validator, I've got this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.visiona.coffeeshop, PID: 16777
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getAnnotatedReturnType()Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedType; 
in class Ljava/lang/reflect/Executable; or its super classes 
(declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.Executable' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
```

Indeed, there is no method `getAnnotatedReturnType` provided by Android `Executable` interface, how can I add this library properly?

Comment: Hibernate Validator lead here. Not really sure what you can do. This method was already around in Java 8 so that's extremely weird Android doesn't support it. We are using this method since Hibernate Validator 6.0 so anything past HV 5.x won't work.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet Well, so the only one thing is to consider about using another library? Those mechanism are great, but really don't know how to provide implementation of reflection libraries in Android

Comment: I don’t know anything about Android. Either there is an update somewhere implementing this method or then you’re stuck with HV 5.x.